# Why is the power of a negative value omitted from my graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I would like to depict a graph that is the power of some values in a continuous way.

```
f <- function(x) {
  return (x^(1/3))
}  

ggplot(data.frame(x=seq(-5,5,length.out=10)), aes(x)) +
  stat_function(fun=f)
```

This only shows the values that are `x > 0`, though if I use online graph tool desmos it shows values of `x < 0` too. In interactive sessions, `-3^(1/3)` returns `-1.44225`.

Why does R omit it and how can I depict the negative x values too?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fractional power of a negative number is a complex number. If you want to include these in your plot, you could show the imaginary and real components separately:

```r
real_part <- function(x) {
  Re(complex(length(x), x, 0)^(1/3))
}

imaginary_part <- function(x) {
  Im(complex(length(x), x, 0)^(1/3))
}
```

We can plot with labels for clarity:

```r
library(geomtextpath)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

ggplot(data.frame(x = seq(-5, 5, length.out = 10)), aes(x)) +
  stat_function(fun = real_part, aes(label = "Real part"), geom = "textpath",
                hjust = 0.8, vjust = -0.2, size = 6) +
  stat_function(fun = imaginary_part, color = "red", linetype = 2, hjust = 0.2,
                aes(label = "Imaginary part"), geom = "textpath", vjust = -0.2,
                size = 6) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the answer but then why does [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) shows the negative parts too, when I type in `x^(1/3)` there? And the result it graphs also seems to be different from yours, so I'm confused.

Comment: @Blaszard the graph in desmos isn't right. It shows the graph of the signed root of the absolute value of x^(1/3), which isn't the same thing. You can get the same plot in R with `function(x) sign(x) * (abs(x))^(1/3)` - but you should be aware that this is not quite correct mathematically.

Answer (score 3):

Exponential functions with a negative base are considered undefined over the set of real numbers. This is since e.g. `(-2)^(m/n)` is impossible if  `n` is even and given any `x` there will be infinitely many fractions of that form which are arbitrarily close to `x`. If you want the cube root you can use

```
cuberoot <- function(x){sign(x)*abs(x)^(1/3)}
```

Answer (score 3):

As @JohnColeman explains, the results of your function are undefined for negative `x`. The reason `-3^(1/3)` seems to work in the console but not your functions is due to [operator precedence](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html). `^` has higher precedence in R than `-`, so your console input is evaluated as:

```
-(3^(1/3))
# -1.44225
```

But when you pass `-3` to your function, it's evaluated as:

```
(-3)^(1/3)
# NaN
```